# How to reduce time for an EC2 instance to launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, virtual-machine

In the AWS EC2 instances if we launch any instance from S3 bucket how long it will take to attach the EBS volume and boot up the server?

In my case i have an DC - DR configuration in AWS using Draas solution  normally my VM specs are

4 Vpcu, 8GB, 100 GB HDD and the EC2 instance is m6a.large

Lambda script is used to launch the instance.

As of now it is taking **13 minutes** to launch from latest snapshot is it nominal or too high

How to reduce the time more up to 4 minutes?

Comment: What do you mean by "launch any instance from S3 bucket"? How is the S3 Bucket involved in launching the EC2 instance? Also, how are you measuring the time -- at what point do you consider it to be 'launched' (eg when it says 'Running', or when your software is responding to requests)?

Comment: Yeah it is EC2 instance launch only.....the point it to be considered launching when it shows running (my software or services only takes 20sec that doesn't matter).

Comment: Launching a Linux instance from an AMI should only take a minute or so. But what do you mean by "launch from latest snapshot" -- are you referring to an AMI? If you try connecting (ssh) to the server after a minute or so, what happens? (Or are you running Windows? It can take a long time.)

Comment: I'm using only Linux machines only... RHEL. Actually my Datacenter's snapshot are getting replicated in the S3 bucket so from the recent snapshot the instance is starting for that how much time will be taken..? Now it's take upto 13-15 min is it normal..?

Comment: Please clarify how you are using AMIs, Snapshots and S3. The normal process it to either use a provided AMI, or use "Create Image" on an existing Amazon EC2 instance to create an AMI. This also results in an Amazon EBS Snapshot being created. Then, you can launch a new EC2 instance using the AMI, without specifically referencing the Snapshot or Amazon S3. Is this how you are launching the instance? Also, please tell us how you are measuring the launch time.